# How to fix my output which is always "null" to 1,2,3 "null"?

Tags: java

I am writing a main method for the purpose of testing some codes, but my main mode have some errors which can't test the code correctly. Could anyone helps me to fix the problem in my main method?

Here is some background of the testing class:

Enter the LLNode class into DrJava:

```
 /**
   * The node of a linked list
   */
   public class LLNode<T> {
   /** the element stored in the node */
   private T element;

    /** a reference to the next node of the list */
    private LLNode<T> next;

   /**
    * the constructor
    * @param element  the element to store in the node
    * @param next  a reference to the next node of the list
    */
     public LLNode(T element, LLNode<T> next) {
     this.element = element;
     this.next = next;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the element stored in the node
    * @return the element stored in the node
    */
  public T getElement() {
     return element;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the next node of the list
   * @return the next node of the list
   */
  public LLNode<T> getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  /**
   * Changes the node that comes after this node in the list
   * @param next  the node that should come after this node in the 
 list.  It can be null.
   */
  public void setNext(LLNode<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

}
```

The rest of the code can be entered in the interactions pane. If you get an error, enter the corrected code. If you get really mixed up, you can reset the interactions pane and try again.

Step 1: Write Java commands to create the following linked list with the variable listHead pointing to the first node of the list:

```
              +---+---+      +---+---+      +---+---+
listHead ---> | 1 | *-+----> | 2 | *-+----> | 3 | *-+--X
              +---+---+      +---+---+      +---+---+
```

Hint: You can do this with 3 lines of code in the Interactions pane. (For fun, try doing it with just one line!) You can test it by typing listHead.getElement(), listHead.getNext().getElement(), listHead.getNext().getNext().getElement(), and listHead.getNext().getNext().getNext() in the Interactions pane, and if your list is correct, the outputs should be 1, 2, 3, and null.

In the above picture, each box refers to a single LLNode object, the left item in the box is the element and the right item is the next reference.

Step 2: Try to create the same linked list, but now use a loop where, in each iteration, it creates a single LLNode instance. To create the three nodes, the loop will need to iterate three times. (Hint: is it easier to create the list forwards or backwards?)

```
import java.util.*;
public class prelab10 {
     public static void main(String args[]){
          LLNode start = null;
          LLNode end = null;
          int i = 0;
        int size = 3;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      LLNode list = new LLNode(1,null);
      LLNode list1 = new LLNode(2,null);
      LLNode list2 = new LLNode(3,null);

      start = list; 
      end = start;

      list.setNext(start);
           start = list;

      list1.setNext(start);
           start = list1;

      list2.setNext(start);
           start = list2;

      LLNode a =start ;

      while(i!= size)

      {
          i++;
          System.out.println(a.getElement()+"<->");
          a = a.getNext();
      }
      while(i == 3)
           System.out.println("null");

}     
}
```

I expect the output is 1,2,3,null instead of null from beginning to the end

Comment: Looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566980/how-to-do-step-2?noredirect=1#comment103452309_58566980

Comment: The hint is telling you to start at the end (the only node that doesn't have a next). Working backwards you should be passing the previously created node into the constructor: `list1 = new LLNode(2, list2)`. The question also recommends that you use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to go line by line and check the structure that you are building.

Actually, you got quite close, the structure that you have built is:

```
list3 -> list2 -> list1 -> list1
```

Note that `list1` is pointing to itself, so if you remove the line `list1.setNext(start)`, you should get:

```
list3 -> list2 -> list1 -> null
```

Here you can see that:

```
public class prelab10 {
  public static void main(String args[]){

    LLNode<Integer> start = null;
    LLNode<Integer> end = null;
    LLNode<Integer> list1 = new LLNode<Integer>(1, null);
    LLNode<Integer> list2 = new LLNode<Integer>(2, null);
    LLNode<Integer> list3 = new LLNode<Integer>(3, null);

    start = list1; 
    end = start;
    // start -> list1
    // end -> list1

    // This one is wrong, list1 should NOT point to itself:
    // list1.setNext(start);
    start = list1;
    // list1.next -> start -> list1
    // start -> list1

    list2.setNext(start);
    start = list2;
    // list2.next -> start -> list1
    // start -> list2

    list3.setNext(start);
    start = list3;
    // list3.next -> start -> list2
    // start -> list3

    LLNode cursor = start;
    // cursor -> start -> list3

    // So, what you have build is:
    // list3 -> list2 -> list1 -> list1

    // Removing list1.setNext(start), you would have:
    // list3 -> list2 -> list1 -> null

    // This loop will never end in your original code, as cursor will never be
    // null, as list1's next pointer points to itself:

    while (cursor != null) {
      System.out.print(cursor.getElement() + " -> ");
      cursor = cursor.getNext();
    }

  }     
}
```

This should help you debug and fix your code.

You might also want to chain/link the nodes in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks, I will carefully read and rearrange my thinking again.